How to loop through a JSON with dynamic properties in Power Automate
I want to use Power Automate to call TSheet timesheets api to get the data and process it. But I'm having difficulties looping through the responded data from TSheet. So here is an example of the responded json:
{
    "results": {
        "timesheets": {
            "1234567": {
                "id": 1234567,
                "state": "CLOSED",
                "user_id": 123456
            },
            "2345678": {
                "id": 415628812,
                "state": "APPROVED",
                "user_id": 234567
            }
        }
    }
}

I have used "Parse JSON" and "Compose" actions trying to format this JSON to an array so that I can use it on the "Apply to Each" action but I haven't figured out how. Passing this json object to "Apply to Each" action will fail because it requires array.
Any help will be appreciated.

Are you open to using a third party connector? If so, the Advanced Data Operations connector can turn that entire structure into key value pairs which in turn creates an array you can loop over and work with dynamically … https://statesolutions.com.au/json-properties-to-name-value-pair-array/ …!

Thanks but no, the data is confidential and it's less likely that the company will pay extra fee for a 3rd party service just for this purpose. I wonder why there isn't a way to iterate through all properties of the JSON object. Maybe there is that I just don't know about.

It's an object, so not directly, no, there is no way.  I will have an option for you though so stay tuned.

Do you need to know the name of the property that houses all of the info or do you just want the info?  i.e. do you need to know "1234567" and "2345678"?

No, I don't need that because that value is actually the "id" in each element. I only need to turn the "timesheets" object into a json array, and then I can use pass it to the "Apply to Each" action. Thanks @Skin

Ok, this isn't overly friendly but will get you a result.

Essentially, you need to convert your JSON to XML and do it that way.
These are the steps ...
Compose Data
This is the JSON you provided simply pasted into that operation.
Compose XML
Here, we convert the JSON to XML.  You do that via this expression ...
xml(outputs('Compose_Data'))

Compose Timesheet Items
This is an XPath query to separate the items out into an array so you can loop over them.
xpath(xml(outputs('Compose_XML')), '//timesheets/*')

For Each Element
Is looping over the results of the previous operation.
outputs('Compose_Timesheet_Items')

Compose Item
Here, we decode the content of the item as it's currently stored as base64.
xml(decodeBase64(item()['$content']))

Compose JSON Item
This is where we can compose a small JSON object that has the data you want from each item.  It uses XPath to pull out each property.
{
  "id": @{first(xpath(xml(outputs('Compose_Item')), '//id/text()'))},
  "state": @{first(xpath(xml(outputs('Compose_Item')), '//state/text()'))},
  "user_id": @{first(xpath(xml(outputs('Compose_Item')), '//user_id/text()'))}
}

From there, you can do what you need to the object.  You can add it to an array or process the data in line.
I should note as well, all of this can be done without looping.
If you use a Select operation instead of the loop, you can get it done a lot quicker.  This is the definition for the Select, you'd need to pick out the parts to set it up ...
{
  "type": "Select",
  "inputs": {
    "from": "@outputs('Compose_Timesheet_Items')",
    "select": {
      "id": "@first(xpath(xml(xml(decodeBase64(item()['$content']))), '//id/text()'))",
      "state": "@first(xpath(xml(xml(decodeBase64(item()['$content']))), '//state/text()'))",
      "user_id": "@first(xpath(xml(xml(decodeBase64(item()['$content']))), '//user_id/text()'))"
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {
    "Compose_Timesheet_Items": [
      "Succeeded"
    ]
  }
}



That works perfectly. Thanks a lot @Skin
